# Vuejs microfrontend with SystemJS / Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, systemjs, micro-frontend

I'm working on a POC to make a VueJS Portal Application that can dynamically load another VueJS sub applications.

I couldn't work with Webpack Module Federation because I need to discover which Application I can "pull" at runtime and not at buildtime.

So I decided to rather use importmap with SystemJS.

I works with simple sub application but when I use Vuetify, I got a lot of errors like:

> [Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.
> [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

And some Vuetify components doesn't work at all.

It's seem to be caused by a duplicated VueJS import (one by webpack, another with systemjs) but I'm not sure (I can access to the same this.$store so...).

Anyway, this is my repo: https://github.com/Saveriu/vue-microfrontends

I tried a lot of example but I didn't find a good one with all my requirements.
If someone can look into it and find a way to fix it, it will be a good example to share about VueJS Microfrontends!

Comment: My first idea would be to dabble with [web component build targets](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component) and do the discovery myself somehow.

Comment: I used lib target but I think it can be doable with webcomponents.
For the discovery and in-browser module import, I use an import-map.json. 
For the POC I put it into the /public folder but for production it will be generated by an rest API.

Answer (score 0):

Make your subapps as WebComponents - here is some information that will help you:

- https://github.com/kartsims/vue-customelement-bundler/tree/rollup
- https://itnext.io/vuidget-how-to-create-an-embeddable-vue-js-widget-with-vue-custom-element-674bdcb96b97
- https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element
- https://filosophy.org/code/bundling-vue-css-and-js-into-a-single-output-file/

Of course you won't be able to share Vuex contents between the subapps or between main app and subapps - you will need to find a more sophisticated way of "shared" state.